# Intersection of compact set with an open set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

If $O$ is the union of two open disjoint sets $O_1$ and $O_2$ in R and C is a compact set with $C \subset O_1 \cup O_2$ then is $O_1 \cap C$ compact? I suspect yes because it looks like $O_1 \cap C$ = C but i'm not sure. If so how would I prove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It need not be equal to $C$ (take for example, $O_1=(-2,2)$, $O_2=(4,8)$, $C=[-1,1]\cup[5,6]$; in this example, $C\nsubseteq O_1$ and $C\nsubseteq O_2$).

Let $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}$ be an open cover for $O_1\cap C$. Intersecting with $O_1$, we may assume that $U_i\subseteq O_1$. Then $\{U_i\}_{i\in I}\cup\{O_2\}$ is an open cover for $C$ (since $O_2$ will cover $C-O_1$). Thus, there is a finite collection, $U_{i_1},\ldots,U_{i_n}$, such that
$$ C\subseteq O_2\cup U_{i_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{i_n}$$
by adding $O_2$ to the finite subcover if necessary.

Now let $x\in O_1\cap C$. Then $x\notin O_2$, so $x\in U_{i_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{i_n}$. Thus, $O_1\cap C\subseteq U_{i_1}\cup\cdots\cup U_{i_n}$.

Hence, any open cover of $O_1\cap C$ has a finite subcover, hence $O_1\cap C$ is compact.

Comment: My reasoning was that if C is compact then it is closed and bounded. Then for 2 disjoint open intervals to cover C, it must be that one of them (say $O_2$) is disjoint from C because if both of them had some overlap with C then since both of them are open, there would be a point missing causing it not to be the case that $C \subset O_1 \cup O_2$. Then from there if one of them is disjoint then the other one fully covers C which means $O_1 \cap C$ = C if $O_1$ is not disjoint from C. Otherwise its the empty set = compact. How would you write it with that reasoning?

Comment: @LTM: Your reasoning is incorrect, as I demonstrated with an explicit example of a $C$ that does not satisfy your claim for either $O_1$ nor $O_2$. “Closed and bounded” does not mean **connected**. I cannot write it “with that reasoning” because the reasoning is **incorrect**.

Comment: @LTM: I gave you an *explicit* example of a $C$ that is compact, two disjoint open sets $O_1$ and $O_2$, with $C\subseteq O_1\cup O_2$, but $C\nsubseteq O_1$ and $C\nsubseteq O_2$. Which part of that *explicit* example did you not see? Use that example with your “reasoning” to see *exactly* where it breaks down, which is pretty much in the second sentence.